# List products in In-App Purchase 2 in Ionic 3

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, in-app-purchase

While testing my app, the data was not fetched and there are no errors showing up.

The status of the products are already on "ready to submit".

I turned on in-app purchase capability as well in Xcode but still, the products are not listed.

My question is, do I need to submit new version of my Live app to test with new In App Purchase Products? or is it okay to test it even I didn't submit new version.

Ionic 3
In-App Purchase 2

```
 export class CardsPage {

  public product: any = {
    name: 'Elite Membership',
    appleProductId: 'ph.elite_membership',
    googleProductId: 'ph.elite_membership'
  };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    public restProvider: RestProvider, 
    private storage: Storage,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public platform: Platform,
    public store: InAppPurchase2) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.configurePurchasing();
    }); 
  }

  configurePurchasing() {
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) { return; }
    let productId;
    try {
      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        productId = this.product.appleProductId;
      } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        productId = this.product.googleProductId;
      }

      // Register Product
      // Set Debug High
      this.store.verbosity = this.store.DEBUG;

      // Register the product with the store
      this.store.register({
        id: productId,
        alias: productId,
        type: this.store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION
      });

      this.registerHandlers(productId);

      InAppPurchase2.getPlugin().ready().then((status) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.store.get(productId)));
        console.log('Store is Ready: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
        console.log('Products: ' + JSON.stringify(this.store.products));

      });

      // Errors On The Specific Product
      this.store.when(productId).error( (error) => {
        alert('An Error Occured' + JSON.stringify(error));
      });
      // Refresh Always
      console.log('Refresh Store');
      this.store.refresh();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error On Store Issues' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }

  registerHandlers(productId) {
    // Handlers
    this.store.when(productId).approved( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      // Purchase was approved
      product.finish();
    });

    this.store.when(productId).registered( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      console.log('Registered: ' + JSON.stringify(product));
    });

    this.store.when(productId).updated( (product: IAPProduct) => {
      console.log('Loaded' + JSON.stringify(product));
    });

    this.store.when(productId).cancelled( (product) => {
      alert('Purchase was Cancelled');
    });

    // Overall Store Error
    this.store.error( (err) => {
      alert('Store Error ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }
```

Comment: I can show it in native Java